# Python Dtrace patched, but still getting "invalid probe specifier" running test scripts

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, cpython, dtrace, probe

I patched Python 2.7.3 with [Issue 13405](http://bugs.python.org/issue13405), then compiled python with the `--with-dtrace` configure option.

When I run the test_dtrace script the tests fail with the error:

> invalid probe specifier

as shown below:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_function_entry_return (test_dtrace.DTraceTestsNormal)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dtrace.py", line 99, in test_function_entry_return
    self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result)
AssertionError: 'dtrace: invalid probe specifier python*$target:::function-entry{    printf("Function entry %d ", timestamp);}python*$target:::function-entry,python*$target:::function-return{    printf("%d\t**%s*%s*%s*%d\\n", timestamp,        probename, copyinstr(arg0),        copyinstr(arg1), arg2);}python*$target:::function-return/(copyinstr(arg0)=="/Users/ramandeep/src/src/Python-2.7.3/dtrace_sample.py") &&(copyinstr(arg1)=="test_entry_return_and_stack")/{    self->trace = 0;}: probe description python*36447:::function-entry does not match any probes' !=  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The probes require a few workarounds:

> It's rather annoying that dtrace doesn't honor the PATH variable, and when you run the strings command on /usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib you'll see that it hardcodes the use of gcc (not even cpp or clang).
>
> Did you run autoconf or autoreconf after applying the patch?  If not,
>   @DTRACEOBJS@ would not be a substitutable string.  It's fairly common (at
>   least in the Python community) to omit modified configure scripts from these
>   sorts of patches because the changes to generated configure scripts between
>   different versions of autoconf are so massive that they dwarf the actual
>   functional changes in the patch, often by a couple orders of magnitude.
>
> Adding this stanza to the top of phelper.d gets past
>   the issues in the headers:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define _SYS_TIME_H_
#define _SYS_SELECT_H_
#define __MATH_H__
#define _OS__OSBYTEORDER_H
#define _FD_SET
#define __GNUC_VA_LIST
#endif /* __APPLE__ */
```

There's also a project to add [python bindings](https://github.com/nshalman/python-usdt) to [libusdt](https://github.com/chrisa/libusdt) and [opendtrace](https://github.com/opendtrace/toolkit/blob/master/Python/Readme) which may help.

**References**

- [Python Tracker Issue 4111: Add Systemtap/DTrace probes](https://bugs.python.org/issue4111)
- [Python Tracker Issue 13405: Add DTrace Probe](http://bugs.python.org/issue13405)
- [Python Tracker Issue 14776: Add SystemTap static markers](https://bugs.python.org/issue14776)
- [Systemtap Static Probes: Python](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SystemtapStaticProbes#Python)
- [Red Hat Bugzilla Issue 545179:  RFE: add systemtap static probes to python runtime](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=545179)
- [DTrace and Perl](https://dgl.cx/2011/01/dtrace-and-perl)
- [Understanding dtrace ustack helpers](https://www.joyent.com/blog/understanding-dtrace-ustack-helpers)
- [Python and dtrace in build 65 (Staring At The C)](https://blogs.oracle.com/levon/entry/python_and_dtrace_in_build)
- [DTrace patch for Python 2.7.x and 3.x](https://www.jcea.es/artic/python_dtrace.htm)
- [Python dtrace tracker Github repo](https://github.com/benesch/python-dtrace-tracker)